# Wheel size for climbing up on inclined surface

Tags: forces, torque, speed

I am going to make a Line follower robot which can climb up on a inclined bridge(45 degree with flat surface). If speed remains constant, Should I use bigger wheel to enable the robot to climb easily?

I think, If wheel size is bigger and speed remains constant, it can apply more torque at same time. So it can take the robot up on the bridge more easily.

Currently,I am using a wheel which has a diameter of 42mm and width 19mm . Now I want to use a wheel which has a diameter of 60mm and width 8mm.

(Note:The torque of the motors are 4 kg.cm and robot's weight is about 500 gram.)

Answer (score 0):

You are right but the size should not be too large as they will shift the centre of mass of robot up and it will increase the chances of robot  to fall, It  depends upon the mass distribution of your robot.

*hope this answer is helpful for you*